# ionic 5 tabs redirect a tab to specific page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

I have 5 tabs in my app. From which I want to redirect the 5th tab to a page in the app automatically. i.e. when the user clicks on tab5 he should be redirected to page called `carts`

I have added carts page in children's path of the 5th tab and tried to redirect. But nothing is happening.
5th tab is not redirecting to carts page

here is the code

app.routing.module

```
{
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/tabbar/tabbar.module').then( m => m.TabbarPageModule)
  },
```

tabbar.routing.module

```
{
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabbarPage,
    children : [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab1/tab1.module').then( m => m.Tab1PageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab2/tab2.module').then( m => m.Tab2PageModule)
      },

      {
        path: 'tab3',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab3/tab3.module').then( m => m.Tab3PageModule)
      },

      {
        path: 'tab4',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab4/tab4.module').then( m => m.Tab4PageModule)
      },

      {
        path: 'tab5',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab5/tab5.module').then( m => m.Tab5PageModule),
      },

      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
```

tab5.routing.module

```
{
    path: '',
    component : Tab5Page,
    children : [

      {
        path : 'carts',
        loadChildren : () => import('../carts/carts.module').then(m => m.CartsPageModule)
      },

      {
        path : '',
        redirectTo : '/tab5/carts',
        pathMatch : 'full'
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    path : '',
    redirectTo : '/tab5/carts',
    pathMatch : 'full'
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just remove the Tabs5Page and load the CartsPage directly in tab 5's routing?

```js
{
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabbarPage,
    children : [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab1/tab1.module').then( m => m.Tab1PageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab2/tab2.module').then( m => m.Tab2PageModule)
      },

      {
        path: 'tab3',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab3/tab3.module').then( m => m.Tab3PageModule)
      },

      {
        path: 'tab4',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab4/tab4.module').then( m => m.Tab4PageModule)
      },

      {
        path: 'tab5',
        loadChildren : () => import('../carts/carts.module').then(m => m.CartsPageModule)
      },

      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
```